# Prevent alert first time using jquery/ javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to attached function on click event on document. My function is attached it but it is calling it also. I don't understand why. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4yHC4/1/)

```
$(function () {
    $('a').click(function () {
        $(document).bind('click', perform)
    })
})
function perform() {
    alert(0)
}
```

Comment: Make it sure that it is not attached multiple time. unbind the event of click before attaching it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the event 'bubbles', firing upon both the `a` element and its parents, you can force jquery to stop further events from firing above this element like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/4yHC4/2/

```
$(function () {
    $('a').click(function (e) {
        $(document).bind('click', perform)
        e.stopPropagation();
    })
})

function perform() {
    alert(0)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because of the click event propagating and bubbling up the DOM. Change your code to:

```
$(function () {
    $('a').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(document).on('click', perform)
    })
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4yHC4/4/)**

Since your link is a descendant of the body element, a click on it actually will travel up the DOM and trigger any click events bound to it's ancestor elements. You can stop this by using [`.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) on the link.

Comment: I wondered if you could clarify exactly the sequence of events here?  Is the original code binding the click event to the document before the event has finished bubbling up the DOM?  So once the 'bubbling' has reached 'document', the click has already been bound to the document?

Comment: that's how I understand it, but bubbling is kinda black magic to me :)

Comment: @RobinL - yes, in your case with your original code the binding takes place first, then the propagation occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one before the click event

```
          $(document).unbind("click");
          $(document).bind("click" , perform);
```

Answer (score 1):

Whats happening is called `event propagation`. When the click event is triggered on the `a` element the `document` gets bound then the click event propagates up to the document and runs your function.

To stop this from happening you run `event.stopPropagation();`. What this does is tell the browser: don't have this click event propagate up.

Your sample code with `event.stopPropagation();`:

```
function perform() {
    alert(0);
}

$(function () { 
    $('a').click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();

        $(document).bind('click',perform);
    });
});
```

Here is a good link: [Event propagation in Javascript](http://blog-en.openalfa.com/event-propagation-in-javascript/)